# Why didn't this OUAT character cut off their hand in hopes of regrowing it?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

I know it might be dumb to continue questioning plot holes in *Once Upon a Time* but...

why didn't or couldn't

> Rumple

cut off their arm [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5emLOxUzHs) in S03E11 and then just regrow it right after like

> Zelena

did 2 seasons later ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5J_CEyQZO8) in S05E01)?

I mean

> If Zelena could cut off her arm to get back magic and then just instantaneously regrow it, why couldn't or didn't Rumple?

---

Edit: Based on answer below, I think it's like...

> So cutting off arm may work for avoiding rumple dying but possibly at the cost of pan's not dying? it's basically the same principle as the ff? (https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99671/why-doesnt-dr-strange-use-the-time-stone-to-do-this)

Comment: IIRC this episode correctly, it's inexplicable. Other than the facts that one may find dismembering themselves cognitively difficult, and the golden rule: *magic comes with a price.*

Comment: @Mazura wait reread answer. edited question. anything to add please? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Might be that I simply missed it, but I haven't seen any reason for Rumple to cut off his hard and grow it back.

He used his shadow to get the dagger, held tight to Pan so Pan couldn't run away, and his only way of saving his son and Bell was to stab Pan and sacrificing himself.

As far as I could see, Rumple was not wearing the magic blocking bracelet.

Comment: Edited question. Look having that bracelet thing means doing no magic. However if you cut off your arm then the bracelet is no longer around you (philosophers may disagree but those are the OUAT rules) and therefore you can do magic if you could do magic before the bracelet was put on you. That's what Zelena did. Rumple was about to do it but then he later decided not to do it. Why didn't he?

Comment: Again - why would Rumple (in that scene atleast) need to cut off his arm?
Zelena cut it off, as you said, so she would lose the bracelet and be able to use magic again.... Rumple was not even wearing the bracelet, he could use magic, there was nothing on his hands/arms that he needed to remove by cutting off a hand.

Comment: Can't open link now but Peter pan put an anti magic bracelet on him

Comment: After watching the entire episode again I noticed that: Gold did not remove the bracelet. I know this for two reasons: the first would be that when Rumple arrives, Pan nods towards Rumple's wrist and says "Still... no magic". The second reason is that following that sentence, Gold said that he doesn't need magic in order to kill Pan.

now, to the question of why he didnt remove the bracelet and magically killed Pan - Both Pan and Gold numerous times said that in order to kill Pan, Gold had to die as well. So there was no reason for Gold to remove the bracelet and magically kill them both

Comment: Yeah there's that: Why again is it that the only way to kill Pan is for Rumple to die?

Comment: You are aware that you are not completely changing your question right?
At first you asked why he didnt cut his hand and then magically killed Pan (which I answered) and then decided that its not your question and completely changed it to something different.

Now, if this is your real question (why he had to die himself in order to kill Pan) then your question is a duplicate of [this Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51430/why-did-he-have-to-die-to-kill-peter-pan)

Comment: thanks. so cutting off arm may work for avoiding rumple dying but possibly at the cost of pan's not dying? it's basically the same principle as the ff? (https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99671/why-doesnt-dr-strange-use-the-time-stone-to-do-this)